# Can't get File Tail working

Tags: ruby, logging, tail

Out of curiosity I tried [file-tail](https://github.com/flori/file-tail) ruby library to see how it works with ruby code. But, the code doesn't seem to be working.

Here is what I tired(**logger.rb**):

```
$:.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)

filename = 'logger.log'

require "file-tail"

File.open(filename) do |log|
  log.extend(File::Tail)
  log.interval = 10
  log.backward(10)
  log.tail { |line| puts line }
end
```

My **logger.log** file is in the same directory. Now, when I run: `$ ruby logger.rb` I see the last 10 lines from my log, but when I open logger.log file append some log data to it, the console doesn't show any progress. I mean it doesn't output the new log I appended.

I thought there may be in an issue with this. So, I tried inheriting and including the File::Tail in the inherited class, like this:

```
$:.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)

filename = 'logger.log'

require "file-tail"

class FileTail < File
  require "file-tail"
  include File::Tail
end

log = FileTail.new(filename)
log.interval = 10
log.backward(10)
log.tail { |line| print line }
```

However this behaves the same way!!

Any pointers?

I am running on MAC OC X 10.8.5 with ruby-2.0.0-p353 installed.

Also, please let me know if anybody has implemented web version of tail in Ruby?

Comment: Did you save your manual updates to the file?

Comment: To log file, right? Yes, I did.

Comment: Tried and it worked for me.

Comment: Maybe the system? I tried again. Didn't work. :/

Comment: Maybe. Are you on windows, by any chance?

Comment: Works for me on OS X 10.9.1 & MRI 2.0, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Bad. This works when I closed all streams of my logger file. I'd opened the file in my ruby code but, didn't close the file stream. Maybe that's why I didn't see any log output on my console using the file-tail.

So, make sure you close all streams of the log/text file you're running with **file-tail** program.